# Find multiple sub-matrices in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to find all the [d1 by d2] sub-matrices that their values reside in a matrix, for example let's say I have the following:

```
pvec = [ 1   1
         2   2 
         3   4
         4   7]

m = [ 1 4 1 1;
      2 2 1 1;
      2 2 2 1;
      3 4 2 1;
      1 1 3 3;
      2 2 5 6 ]
```

Index points for [1 1]: (1,3), (1,4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (5,1) and (5,2). Those points should be returned together for all row occurrences like the [1 1] case (I don't care if they are actual (i,j) points or linear indexes).

As I said I know how to perform this for a fixed pvec like this:

```
m(find(ismember(m, pvec(1, :)) & ismember(m, pvec(2, :)) & ismember(m, pvec(3, :))))
```

I think you get the point, but the thing is that pvec might change in size in each iteration of the script and I don't know how to get them all at once. Anyone has any idea how to do this?

I found the answer myself; although not very elegant.

```
idc = [];
Ig = imread(someimg);
padvec = [ ... ] % some pad vec
for i = 1:size(padvec,1)
    idc = [idc, find(ismember(Ig, padvec(i, :)))'];
end
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `m` as well and show what the output should be for that `pvec` example

Comment: @Dan there you go, hopefully I clarified what I want a bit. Thanks!

Comment: I tried that function that was proposed as a solution there, in my case it returns a zero matrix. Not what I wanted.

Comment: @jtimz please show the code for that attempt?

Comment: I found it @Dan, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
pvec = [ 2   2 
         3   4
         4   7]

m = [1, 4
     2, 2
     2, 2
     3, 4
     1, 1
     2, 2]

m(ismember(m,pvec, 'rows'), :)

ans =

   2   2
   2   2
   3   4
   2   2
```